# Compile-Time Function Execution

Tags: c, gcc, compile-time

Is there a way to perform [compile-time function execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution) in C? With GCC? I've only seen this available using [constexpr in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-compile-time-processing-with-constexpr.html).

Comment: Depending on the code, the compiler might optimize it to a simple value, but no there's no standard way for that in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as there are only constants involved in an expression, it will get calculated at compile-time. C++ `constexpr` is mostly a type safe way of doing so without involving macros. In C, there are only macros. For example:

```
#define CIRCLE_AREA(r) (int32_t)( (double)(r) * (double)(r) * M_PI )

int32_t area = CIRCLE_AREA(5);
```

performs all calculations at compile-time, so it is equivalent to writing:

```
int32_t area = 78;
```

Comment: `static inline int32_t circle_area(double r) { return r * r * M_PI; }`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That might force the calculation to be done in runtime, I believe.

Comment: Is this possible with constant strings?

Comment: @user10984587 Yes, indeed. Which allows you to do various fun tricks at compile-time, for example things [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31051026/584518).

Comment: GCC 5.3.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.4.  Source: `int main(void)
{
    int32_t area1 = CIRCLE_AREA(5);
    int32_t area2 = circle_area(5);
    printf("%d vs %d\n", area1, area2);
    return 0;
}` — assembler output (most relevant bit):
       `movl    $78, %edx` –
        `movl    $78, %esi` –
       `leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi` –
       `xorl    %eax, %eax` –
        `call    _printf` —
That looks to me as though both function and macro were expanded to 78 by the compiler.

Comment: @Lundin under the as-if rule anything that doesn't depend on external input can be done at compile-time. Also the standard does not require that your code happen at compile-time. We are really discussing the expected behaviour of common compilers.

Comment: The difference is that calling a function is a "side effect", as specified by the rules for the "abstract machine". Which is why I think that the inline function might not be executed at compile time, because calling it would be a side effect. I'm not certain how aggressively a compiler is allowed to optimize away functions without breaking the rules of the abstract machine.