# Relative path for __FILE__ and PDB

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, debug-symbols

I want to hide machine specific path part from executable.

Is it possible to force relative path for PDB symbols and `__FILE__` macro?

So that some/all initial parts of path are not put into file?

I use MSVC, GCC solutions will not work.

All options are following:

```
/permissive- /MP /GS /Zc:rvalueCast /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"
<some path here>" /Qspectre-load /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"<some path here>"
/Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D
"_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1
/GR- /Gd /Oy- /MTd /openmp- /Fa"<some path here>" /EHa /nologo
/Fo"<some path here>" /Fp"<some path here>" /diagnostics:classic
```

Comment: I don't know about VS, so I don't know if the behaviour of the macro can be configured. But instead of doing that, you can remove the parent path at runtime.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path)

Comment: duplicates: [How do I configure MSVC to show relative path for header files using `__FILE__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41567178/995714), [`__FILE__` macro shows full path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8487986/995714), [C++ `__FILE__` macro with absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50124235/995714)

Comment: No, sorry, I need MSVC solution.

Comment: there are many Windows and MSVC solutions in the other question

Comment: The question is not how to extract base name from file path. The question is how to prevent full path from compiled executable in the first place.

Comment: Besides, use `/PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%` to hide the absolute path to the PDB file in the executable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176185/19048941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile your program without [/FC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fc-full-path-of-source-code-file-in-diagnostics?view=vs-2019) and [/ZI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019) options.

Comment: Nice. But there will still be an absolute path to the PDB if you look into the target binary.

Comment: @WildernessRanger you might want to use that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbaltpath-use-alternate-pdb-path?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019