# How to write a macro to convert member function to a string of its name?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I want to write

```cpp
ProgressFunction.BindUFunction(this, NAMEOF(&MyActor::HandleProgress));
```

instead of

```cpp
ProgressFunction.BindUFunction(this, "HandleProgress");
```

where `BindUFunction`'s second parameter can only accept `TCHAR*`.

## Question

How to define `NAMEOF` macro to convert `&Whatever::FunctionName` to `"FunctionName"`?

Comment: This cannot be done in C++. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Why do you want to write `NAMEOF(&MyActor::HandleProgress)` instead of `NAMEOF(HandleProgress)`? You like making work for yourself? Or do you have a use in mind that does not appear in the question?

Comment: @JaMiT Good point, but did you clock his user ID? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stringify the argument and find the last `:` in it.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#define NAMEOF(x)   (strrchr(#x, ':') ? strrchr(#x, ':') + 1 : #x)
int main() {
    std::cout << NAMEOF(&MyActor::HandleProgress);
}
```

This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237385/9072753 .

Comment: Oh right, that'll do it (how _dare_ you use C functions!)

Comment: @TheRealMasochist MSVC has a wide string equivalent (`_tcsrchr` handles both) if you need it.  And declare that parameter `const`!

Comment: OK. It works as well for `NAMEOF(HandleProgress)`.

Comment: Yep, that's what that ternary operator is in there for